# Why does it throw an error cannot read property of undefined (reading 'length') when running a GraphQL Subscription with Redis?

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, graphql, nestjs

Overview

- Working on a NestJS project with GraphQL using a laptop with Window OS
- Experimenting with GraphQL Subscriptions using `graphql-redis-subscription@2.5.0` package
- Redis is used in a docker container, see the `docker-compose.yml` below
- The problem arose when the subscription `postAdded` is executed in GraphQL Playground. Instead of hanging to listen for events, it had crashed before I performed `createPost` mutation.

My code (I only include some important details)

posts.resolver.ts

```js
import { Inject, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Args, Context, Mutation, Resolver, Subscription } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { RedisPubSub } from 'graphql-redis-subscriptions';
import { GraphqlJwtAuthGuard } from '../auth/guards';
import { RequestWithUser } from '../auth/interfaces';
import { PUB_SUB } from '../pubsub/pubsub.module'

const POST_ADDED_EVENT = 'postAdded';

@Resolver(() => Post)
export class PostsResolver {
  constructor(
    private postsService: PostsService,
    @Inject(PUB_SUB) private pubSub: RedisPubSub,
  ) {}

  // my subscription (issue)
  @Subscription(() => Post)
  postAdded() {
    return this.pubSub.asyncIterator(POST_ADDED_EVENT);
  }

  // createPost method
  @Mutation(() => Post)
  @UseGuards(GraphqlJwtAuthGuard)
  async createPost(
    @Args('input') createPostInput: CreatePostInput,
    @Context() context: { req: RequestWithUser },
  ) {
    // just create a new post (assuming it works)
    const newPost = await this.postsService.create(
      createPostInput,
      context.req.user,
    );
    this.pubSub.publish(POST_ADDED_EVENT, { postAdded: newPost });
    return newPost;
  }
}
```

pubsub.module.ts

```js
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { RedisPubSub } from 'graphql-redis-subscriptions';
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';

export const PUB_SUB = 'PUB_SUB';

@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: PUB_SUB,
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) =>
        new RedisPubSub({
          connection: {
            host: configService.get('REDIS_HOST'),
            port: configService.get('REDIS_PORT'),
          },
        }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    },
  ],
  exports: [PUB_SUB],
})
export class PubSubModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { PubSubModule } from './pubsub/pubsub.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      playground: true,
      autoSchemaFile: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
      installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
    }),
    PubSubModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      validationSchema: Joi.object({
        REDIS_HOST: Joi.string().required(),
        REDIS_PORT: Joi.number().required()
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AppService, AppResolver],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  redis-commander:
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

All the environment variables have already been defined in `.env` file.

```
REDIS_HOST="localhost"
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

When I run `yarn start:dev` and execute the subscription in GraphQL Playground

```
subscription {
  postAdded {
    id
    title
    paragraphs
  }
}
```

it raises an error like this:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "postAdded"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The terminal that monitors NestJS also raises an error like this:

```
[Nest] 8080  - 07/21/2022, 9:30:24 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (C:\Users\HP\nestjs-project\node_modules\redis-parser\lib\parser.js:530:38)
    at Object.data (C:\Users\HP\nestjs-project\node_modules\ioredis\built\DataHandler.js:25:20)  
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (C:\Users\HP\nestjs-project\node_modules\src\TransformOperationExecutor.ts:207:39)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (C:\Users\HP\nestjs-project\node_modules\src\TransformOperationExecutor.ts:327:31)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (C:\Users\HP\nestjs-project\node_modules\src\TransformOperationExecutor.ts:327:31)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (C:\Users\HP\nestjs-project\node_modules\src\TransformOperationExecutor.ts:327:31)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (C:\Users\HP\nestjs-project\node_modules\src\TransformOperationExecutor.ts:327:31)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (C:\Users\HP\nestjs-project\node_modules\src\TransformOperationExecutor.ts:327:31)
    at ClassTransformer.instanceToPlain (C:\Users\HP\nestjs-project\node_modules\src\ClassTransformer.ts:25:21)
    at Object.classToPlain (C:\Users\HP\nestjs-project\node_modules\src\index.ts:23:27)
```

I have installed all the necessary dependencies like `ioredis`, `graphql-redis-subscriptions` and even `graphql-subscriptions` but the errors still exist. Redis also seems to be running properly.

I have tried reading the error logs but it did not occur in my source code and doing some research on StackOverFlow but none seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you by any chance using a global `ClassSerializerInterceptor`?? Because I was running into the same problem just today and I solved by removing the interceptor. It happened because the subscription needs to receive an instance of `AsyncIterable` but the class serializer turns it into a plain object.

Apart from that I would recommend you change the `GraphQl` config, remove the `installSubscriptionHandlers` and change the config like this:

```js
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  playground: true,
  autoSchemaFile: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
  // remove this option: 
  // installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
  // add the following:
  subscriptions: {
    "graphql-ws": true // or config object
  }
}),
```

You can read more about it in the [nestjs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/subscriptions#enable-subscriptions-with-apollo-driver)

I hope this solves your problem.